# A very basic piece of code `slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I'm becoming stunned with this super simple code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
rp1 = ['id', 'key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5']
rp2 = ['id', 'key1', 'key2']

rp1_keys = list(set(rp1).difference(set(rp2)))

print("%s, Type: %s/n" % (rp1_keys, type(rp1_keys)))

if 'id' not in rp1_keys:
    rp1_keys.index(0,'id')
```

this is the exit:

```
===>  ['key3', 'key5', 'key4'] type : <type 'list'>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/py.py", line 11, in <module>
    rp1_keys.index(0,'id')
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: `'id'` is a string, you can't use it in the `index()` method.

Comment: What are you expecting that line to do?

Comment: What do you intend `rp1_keys.index(0, 'id')` to mean? The first argument to `index` is a value to look for; the second is a starting index other than 0 to restrict the range of the search, and `'id'` is not a valid list index.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `rp1_keys.index(0,'id')`? It looks like you do not use it appropriately.

Comment: Did you mean `.insert` instead of `.index`?

Answer (score 6):

Not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here, but if I got it correctly and you want to add the `id` element at the 0th index, you should use the `insert` method, not the `index` method:

```
rp1_keys.insert(0, 'id')
```

Comment: Yes, this is. I'm just a tad stupid, indeed ;)

Tks!